# Disk block size reported as 1

Tags: linux, raid, hard-drive

When i run

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

I get ( notice the block size of sd4 )

```
major minor  #blocks  name

   8     0 1169686528 sda
   8     1     104391 sda1
   8     2    2096482 sda2
   8     3    2096482 sda3
   8     4          1 sda4
   8     5 1165387198 sda5
```

but if I run

```
/sbin/fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

I get again ( notice sda4 )

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1197.7 GB, 1197759004672 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 145619 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              14         274     2096482+  83  Linux
/dev/sda3             275         535     2096482+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4             536      145619  1165387230    5  Extended
/dev/sda5             536      145619  1165387198+  83  Linux
```

This may have something to do with the servers raid configuration as the sda4 is not even mounted or in fstab.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/sda4` is showing as having no useful size because it is, in effect, "not a partition".  It's an "extended" partition, that is, a container for other partitions.  In short, it is a strange and annoying artifact of the limitations of the DOS format partition table.  You can ignore it for the purposes of answering the question "what partitions do I have?"

For a ridiculous amount of information on the format and it's history, [consult Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Boot_Record).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I suspected as much but had to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

look at the start and end cylinders on sda4 and sda5, i think something happened with fdisk and sda5 has overwritten sda4.

Try partitioning sda4 and sda5 again

Comment: Good ghods no.  Don't format `/dev/sda4`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too after asking the question, But then I noticed the extended , could it mean that the extended partition doesn't consume any blocks?

Comment: sorry i meant partition. i must admit i did wonder if the extended tag caused this but i couldn't find any info on it.